# Unslider set different pause length for each slide

Tags: jquery, unslider

I was wondering if it was possible to create an Unslider image slider where the pause length is different for certain slides? For example, I want slide 1 to display for 5 seconds and slide 2 to display for 10 seconds. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unslider doesn't have this functionality built in, so we have to do it ourselves using Unslider's methods and some jQuery. Here is what I came up with when I ran into the same problem.

The "Autoplay" option has to be false (the default setting) for this to work:

```
// Initialize Unslider
var slider = jQuery('#unslider').unslider();

// Array of the times you want for each slide.
var slideTimes = [5000,10000];

// Move the slider to the next slide and start the timer
function timeToNextSlide(ms){
  slideTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    slider.data('unslider')['next']();
  }, ms);
}

// Every time the slide changes
slider.on('unslider.change', function(event, index, slide) {

  // Clear the timeout in case user clicks the navigation
  clearTimeout(slideTimeout);

  // Reset the timeout to the next slide's time
  timeToNextSlide(slideTimes[index]);

});

// Start the slider
timeToNextSlide(slideTimes[0]);
```